# WPF width of window not correct

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to fit an exact amount of list items in the viewbox of my window so I retrieve the width of the corresponding `ListBox` and divide it by the amount I need (in this case 7) like this:

```
Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=WeekView, Converter={StaticResource DivideBySeven}}"
```

The width of my window is 800 and I checked inside the converter what values it gets (784 for the ListBox what seems reasonable) and what value it returns (112, if my math is correct this is also correct).

Problem is my app looks like this:
[image: calculated item width]

I thought ok maybe some calculation got wrong and manually set the item width to 100 (so 700 with all) and I got this:

[image: 100 item width]

And on the right side there are not 84 (whatever unit is used) of space.

**EDIT:** If I resize the window to fullscreen the calculation seems to be correct but I also don't know why or what is going wrong.

Any ideas what I made wrong or how I can get the behaviour I want?

**EDIT2:**
This is the code to reproduce the issue:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: To little code to be sure, but could be because of paddings/margins. Please provide the code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Edited my post to include the MainWindow which can reproduce the issue

Comment: Why not use a uniformgrid for the itemspanel?

Comment: Thx did not know yet about this one.

Comment: Why don't you use a `ListView` with `GridView` as view instead of a `ListBox`?

Comment: The columns of a gridview have absolute width. You can't use * like you can with a datagrid column.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple different problems:

1. Don't rely on the Window for calculating precise Width and Height for your content. The Window has invisible OS-level elements that factor into its total size.

Solution: Remove the Height and Width from your Window and use `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"` instead. Set your precise Width and Height in your root layout element.

2. There are hidden Padding, Margin, and BorderThickness values in many controls.

Solution: I highly recommend that you use Snoop for WPF or the built-in Visual Studio tools to look at elements at runtime and see what they are using. You can then override these values (in most cases) via styles, etc.

Here is an edited version of your example that works:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid
        Width="800"
        Height="350">
        <ListBox
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
            <StackPanel Width="112" />
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tired this code?

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
        <StackPanel Width="*" />
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```