# Main Window won't take up right half of screen in minimal WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I would like to have my main application window occupy half of my monitor when launching my WPF app. In case I am using several monitors, I would like for the window to occupy the last of those monitors. Here's what I've tried so far:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Line
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Screen[] allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
            int noScreens = allScreens.Length;
            double lastScreenWidth = allScreens[noScreens - 1].Bounds.Width;
            double lastScreenHeight = allScreens[noScreens - 1].Bounds.Height;
            double totalWidth = allScreens.Sum(s => s.Bounds.Width);
            
            this.Left = totalWidth - lastScreenWidth / 2;
            this.Width = lastScreenWidth / 2;
            this.Top = 0;
            this.Height = lastScreenHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

I tested this while using only one monitor and here's the result:

[image]

When I drag the main window to the middle of the screen it also looks like the window too wide:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? Why won't the app take up the right half of my last monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Window width and height not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242264/10706024)

> Don't rely on the Window for calculating precise Width and Height for your content. The Window has invisible OS-level elements that factor into its total size.
>
> Solution: Remove the Height and Width from your Window and use
> SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" instead. Set your precise Width and
> Height in your root layout element.

and based on [how to position a window on multi-monitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50338793/10706024)

I've successfully tested this solution

### XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp8"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindowName"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Border x:Name="border" Background="LightBlue"/>
</Window>
```

### CodeBehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Screen[] allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
        Screen lastScreen = allScreens[allScreens.Length - 1];

        var p = this.PointFromScreen(new Point(lastScreen.WorkingArea.X, lastScreen.WorkingArea.Y));
     
        border.Width = lastScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2;
        border.Height = lastScreen.WorkingArea.Height;

        this.Top = 0;
        this.Left += (p.X + border.Width);
    }
}
```